# How to select nodes from a xml tree that contains a specific children using tinyxml2

Tags: xml, tinyxml2

From the tree below :

```
<a>
    <b name = "b1"></b>
    <b name = "b2">
        <c/>
    </b>
    <b name = "b3"></b>
</a>
```

All the elements in b which have the child element c. In-short how to query the xml tree for the xpath `"/b[c]"` using tinyxml2.

Comment: `//b[c]` since it's a relative path

Comment: tinyxml2 does noty support using xpath queries to my knowledge and you have to traverse the tree data yourself.

Comment: Consider pugixml (https://github.com/zeux/pugixml). I have not used it but it does have xpath support.